# does tcl lrange create under the hood a new copy or not of the original list

Tags: list, memory, tcl

let us say that I have a massive list variable. If I reference a range from the list by using the `lrange` commands, is tcl creating a copy of the range, while retaining the original list (assuming that return value is not saved into a variable), or using some immutable reference "shtick" to save memory?

For example: Let us say that I have list variable biggie, and that ~99% of the memory footprint of my script is on saving the biggie list. Will this line will cause my script to almost double its' memory footprint?

```
foreach [ lrange $biggie 1 end-1 ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lrange` command copies the list elements. The amount of memory consumed might not *double* though; the elements that are present in both lists will be handled by reference. The memory that will be duplicated will be the memory to store the array of pointers to the elements; which will be 4 bytes per element on 32-bit systems and 8 bytes per element on 64-bit systems (plus a minuscule amount of fixed overhead).

Any string representation of the list(s) will not be shared at all.

Comment: Thanks. So the bigger the elements, the smaller the relative footprint.
Great.